# How to paste sentences in a column structure together as one 'book'?

Tags: r, string

Let's say I have a book represented in a data frame by having a different row for every cell. The dataframe would be created like this:

```
data.frame(Bookname = c("This is sentence 1.", "This is sentence 2.",
                    "This is sentence 3.", "...", "This is sentence n."))
```

Resulting in:

```
Bookname
"This is sentence 1."
"This is sentence 2."
"This is sentence 3."
...
"This is sentence n."
```

How would I make this book as one single string? So that the output looks like:

```
Bookname
"This is sentence 1. This is sentence 2. This is sentence 3. ... This is sentence n."
```

Comment: Look at `paste` and `collapse` argument

Comment: @arg0naut, how would you use the `collapse` argument in this case?

Comment: `paste(c("a", "b", "c"), collapse = " ")`

Comment: Try out `paste(unlist(df), collapse = " ")` or `paste(df$Bookname, collapse = " ")`

Comment: Thanks @ANG, that worked perfectly!